# Short-circuiting events in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, events, dom-events, event-bubbling

I have a D3 (v4) visualization with a lot of shapes that, in some cases, animate to new positions over the course of about three seconds. These shapes have click and mouseover event listeners that I want to be active only when the viz is not moving.

The naive way to do this is simple. I have a boolean variable called `is_animating` that is set to `true` when the animation starts and `false` on the callback, so I just added this to the event listeners:

```
shapes.on("click", function(d) {
  if (is_animating) {
    return;
  }
  // otherwise, business as usual
})
```

That's fine, but I plan to add a lot of event listeners to the shapes and would love it if there was a more elegant way to intercept the events higher in the bubbling and just do this once instead of adding this check to every event. But I don't fully understand `d3.event` and how it handles bubbling. Is there a simple "master event listenever," if you will, that would fire any time a user tries to do something, which could short-circuit the event if `is_animating` is true?

Answer (score 3):

There is a way in the D3 transitions API to control whether there are any active transitions associated with a given node ([d3.active](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#active)).

You could use it to detect active transitions on a node without introducing an additional variable.

```
shapes.on("click", function(d) {
  if (d3.active(this)) {
    return;
  }
  // otherwise, business as usual
})
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know! This would still mean doing a check instead every listener, but very useful info.

Answer (score 0):

If it's applicable to the way you've set things up, you can wait until the transition ends before registering the event listener:

```
shapes
  .transition()
  .attr(...) // apply new positions, styles, etc
  .on('end', function() {
    // called per element once its transition has completed
    d3.select(this)
      .on('click', function() { /* business as usual */ })
  })
```

Another useful bit that might come into play for you is that you do not necessarily have to register the event listeners on the `shapes` selection, which yields multiple listeners. Instead, you can subscribe to their parent's events. If that parent were an svg in a d3 selection, it would look like this

```
svg // assumes svg is a d3 selection containing every shape
  .on('click', function() {
    // to get the clicked element
    d3.select(d3.event.target)
      .attr(...)

    // or, if you just want d, the datum of the shape
    // that was clicked:
    var d = select(d3.event.target).datum()
  })
```

I don't think there's a way to prevent the bubbling as you described. I don't know why; I'd expect it to work, but my testing didn't succeed. It should be noted though that even if you were able to stop propagation, it would be the propagation from child to parent, NOT parent to child.

Comment: Both good ideas! I agree that it seems like there should be a bubbling solution, but I can't get it to work either -- and good point about the direction. Maybe the solution is to intercept during the _capturing_ phase?